# Using Simple HTML DOM to extract an 'a' URL

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have this code for scraping team names from a table

```
$url = 'http://fantasy.premierleague.com/my-leagues/303/standings/';
$html = @file_get_html($url);
//Cut out the table
$FullTable = $html->find('table[class=ismStandingsTable]',0);
//get the text from the 3rd cell in the row 
$teamname = $FullTable->find('td',2)->innertext;
echo $teamname;
```

This much works.. and gives this output....

```
<a href="/entry/110291/event-history/33/">Why Always Me?</a>
```

But when I add these lines..

```
$teamdetails = $teamname->find('a')->href;
echo $teamdetails;
```

I get completely blank output.

Any idea why? I am trying to get the `/entry/110291/event-history/33/` as one variable, and the `Why Always Me?` as another.

Comment: Did you check the `$teamdetails` ? as you are assigning the value of `$FullTable->find('td',2)->innertext` may be its no more an object, but a simple string. In this case, yous should make a preg_match to extract your `href`. And what contain `$teamname` .?

Comment: Thanks.. I just got this working. I'm not entirely sure why, but I can't ->find stuff within $teamname, so I just did `$teamname = $FullTable->find('td',2)->find('a',0)->href;` and `$teamname = $FullTable->find('td',2)->find('a',0)->innertext;` and it gives exactly the values I need.

Comment: [Enable PHP error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html). When you get a blank page, the error log then contains the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead do this:

```
$tdhtml = DOMDocument::loadHTML($teamdetails);
$link = $tdhtml->getElementsByTagName('a');

$url = $link->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$teamdetails = $teamname->find('a')->href;
               ^^^^^^^^^---- never defined in your code
```

I also fail to see how your "works" code could possibly work. You don't define `$teamname` in there either, so all you'd never get is the output of a null/undefined variable, which is...no output all.

Comment: ok.. I don't know how you code php, but I nearly never have to define variables when doing simple stuff like this. That isn't the reason why it isn't working. I'm on a windows host.. Maybe linux is more strict?

Comment: php doesn't require variables to be predefined, but you're saying you've got the output you want, but the code as provided above could not possibly output anything, since you're doing `echo $undefinedvar`.

Comment: The first bit of code I posted does output exactly the info I need. The latter bit of code didn't work, but I've since fixed it, and I still didn't need to define anything in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Marc B is right, I get that you don't have to initialize a variable, but he is saying you are trying to access a property of said variable:

```
$teamdetails = $teamname->find('a')->href;
           ^^^^^^^^^---- never defined in your code
```

This is essentially:

```
$teamname = null;
$teamname->find('a')->href;
```

Comment: You and Marc B may be right, but you really haven't helped me in any way at all as you haven't explained how I can fix it nor said a way of getting what I'm looking for. I know you upvoted it, but that's bad practise to upvote answers that really don't answer anything. For example `$FullTable` is also never defined, but I can still do similar ->find matches on that. This is why your answer only confuses rather than helps. I got it working by doing `$teamname = $FullTable->find('td',2)->find('a',0)->innertext;`

Comment: `$FullTable = $html->find('table[class=ismStandingsTable]',0);`
It's defined.  He's pointing out that you should do 
`$href = $teamdetails->find('a')->href;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your example is that $teamname is a string and you're treating it like a simple_html_dom_node